# Drawbacks of having large Android App Size on device

Tags: android, android-storage

It is a known fact that the Application size on Play store and App size on the device is different. Application size on devices tends to grow based on users' usage.

Are there any drawbacks if the Application size on the device is larger? Particularly will there be performance issues while using the Application?

One known thing is that a larger app size on a low memory device will be a concern for users.

Comment: large size is not very relevant performance, but Increase the probability of installation failures on unstable networks. and Wi-Fi and unlimited data plans may be taken for granted in some regions, but for the vast majority of users, data speed is a major issue. These users are more likely to cancel the app they are downloading after checking the amount of data remaining. I recommend this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEuwVWpYBOY.

Comment: @AshtonYoon Please read my question again. Question is not about APK size on Playstore.

Comment: "Are there any drawbacks if the Application size on the device is larger? Particularly will there be performance issues while using the Application? " -> It depends, if you are running app on a device which is almost full of storage then if your app requires extra resources the the OS will fail to allocate those to your app. If you are running app on the new device which is empty then there will be no issues. But as a developer it's recommended to use resources wisely and only use resources which are needed. Less is more